# How to use supplier interface to create instances of different classes?

Tags: java, lambda, method-reference, supplier

Example code:

```
public void convertAndThrow(BusinessException e) throws ApiException {
    if (e.getKey().equals("0x42")) {
        throw new ApiConflict(e, 110);
    }
    throw new ApiInternalError(e, 0);
}
```

The `BusinessException` has a *key* (basically a numeric return code from another component, that shows up as string on our side). Now arbitrary `BusinessException` instances need to be converted into (rest) ApiExceptions. The above example would result in 409 "conflict" for "0x42", and a 500 "internal error" otherwise.

Note: the constructors take the same number of arguments (with the same meaning, the underlying exception, and some "sub" return code).

Now I would like to have a map that allows me to get **something** that I can then use to create the required ApiException instance. The following doesn't work, as `Supplier.get()` doesn't take any parameter, it is just meant to outline what I would like to have:

```
Map<String, Supplier<ApiException>> exceptionsByKey = new HashMap<>();
exceptionsByKey.put("0x42", somethingTakingAnExceptionCreatingApiConflict(110));
```

so that I can later simply do:

```
throw exceptionsByKey.get(key).get(e);
```

In other words:

- I want to put my different cases into a map
- map key: the "return code"
- map value: something that builds me specific ApiExceptions

Comment: Note: I did struggle with the wording in my question. If you have ideas how to improve that part, you are welcome to edit directly, or to leave a comment here.

Comment: You could use `Function` instead of `Supplier` as value in the `Map`.